# Reduce matrix rows with CUDA

Tags: c, matrix, cuda

```
Windows 7, NVidia GeForce 425M.
```

I wrote a simple CUDA code which calculates the row sums of a matrix.
The matrix has uni-dimensional representation (pointer to a float).

The serial version of code is below (it has `2` loops, as expected):

```
void serial_rowSum (float* m, float* output, int nrow, int ncol) {
    float sum;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nrow ; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < ncol ; j++)
            sum += m[i*ncol+j];
        output[i] = sum;
    }
}
```

Inside the CUDA code, I call the kernel function sweeping the matrix by rows. Below, the kernel call snippet:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock((unsigned int) nThreadsPerBlock); // has to be multiple of 32
dim3 blocksPerGrid((unsigned int) ceil(nrow/(float) nThreadsPerBlock)); 

kernel_rowSum<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_m, d_output, nrow, ncol);
```

and the kernel function which performs the parallel sum of the rows (still has `1` loop):

```
__global__ void kernel_rowSum(float *m, float *s, int nrow, int ncol) {

    int rowIdx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (rowIdx < nrow) {
        float sum=0;
        for (int k = 0 ; k < ncol ; k++)
            sum+=m[rowIdx*ncol+k];
        s[rowIdx] = sum;            
    }

}
```

So far so good. The serial and parallel (CUDA) results are equal.

The whole point is that the CUDA version takes almost twice the time of the serial one to compute, even if I change the `nThreadsPerBlock` parameter: I tested `nThreadsPerBlock` from `32` to `1024` (maximum number of threads per block allowed for my card).

IMO, the matrix dimension is big enough to justify parallelization: `90,000 x 1,000`.

Below, I report the time elapsed for the serial and parallel versions using different `nThreadsPerBlock`. Time reported in `msec` over an average of `100` samples:

Matrix: nrow = 90000 x ncol = 1000

Serial: Average Time Elapsed per Sample in msec (`100` samples): `289.18`.

CUDA (`32` ThreadsPerBlock): Average Time Elapsed per Sample in msec (`100` samples): `497.11`.

CUDA (`1024` ThreadsPerBlock): Average Time Elapsed per Sample in msec (`100` samples): `699.66`.

Just in case, the version with `32`/`1024` `nThreadsPerBlock` is the fastest/slowest one.

I understand that there is a kind of overhead when copying from Host to Device and the other way around, but maybe the slowness is because I am not implementing the fastest code.

Since I am far from being a CUDA expert:

**Am I coding the fastest version for this task? How could I improve my code?
Can I get rid of the loop in the kernel function?**

Any thoughts appreciated.

### **EDIT 1**

Although I describe a standard `rowSum`, I am interested in the `AND`/`OR` operation of rows which have `(0;1}` values, like `rowAND`/`rowOR`. That said, it doesn't allow me to exploit the `cuBLAS` multiply by `1`'s `COL` column vector trick, as suggested by some commentators.

### **EDIT 2**

As suggest by users other users and here endorsed:

**FORGET ABOUT TRYING TO WRITE YOUR OWN FUNCTIONS**, use Thrust library instead and the magic comes.

Comment: Google "CUDA memory coalescing" and start reading - therein lies your problem.

Comment: @talonmies, thanks a lot. If it does not bug u, could you please answer the question with a code snippet? Does it still have an internal kernel loop?

Comment: Summing the elements of an array can be effectively performed in parallel by a "reduction" operation. In your case, the reduction could be applied row-wise, so that the involved arrays would be the different rows. Perhaps, having a look at the reduction example of the SDK would be recommendable, besides of course dealing with coalescence, as suggested by talonmies?

Comment: @JackOLantern, thanks for your comment. if possible, cloud you please paste/answer the question with a snippet of code using reduction? (I guess you are referring to operations using Thrust library, am I wrong?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you mentioned you need general reduction algorithm other than sum only. I will try to give 3 approaches here. kernel approach may have the highest performance. thrust approach is easiest to implement. cuBLAS approach works only with sum and have good performance.

### Kernel Approach

[Here's a very good doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) introducing how to optimize standard parallel reduction. Standard reduction can be divide into 2 stages.

1. Multiple thread blocks each reduces one part of the data;
2. One thread block reduces from result of stage 1 to the final 1 element.

For your multi-reduction (reduce rows of mat) problem, only stage 1 is enough. The idea is to reduce 1 row per thread block. For further considerations like multi-row per thread block or 1 row per multiple thread blocks, you can refer to the [paper provided by @Novak](http://gpulab.imm.dtu.dk/papers/Sorensen2012_Euro-Par.pdf). This may improve the performance more, especially for matrices with bad shape.

### Thrust Approach

General multi-reduction can be done by `thrust::reduction_by_key` in a few minutes. You can find some discussions here [Determining the least element and its position in each matrix column with CUDA Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698969/cuda-thrust-find-index-of-minimum-value-among-multiple-vectors/17718468#17718468).

However `thrust::reduction_by_key` does not assume each row has the same length, so you will get performance penalty. Another post [How to normalize matrix columns in CUDA with max performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211093/how-to-normalize-matrix-columns-in-cuda-with-max-performance) gives profiling comparison between `thrust::reduction_by_key` and cuBLAS approach on sum of rows. It may give you a basic understanding about the performance.

### cuBLAS Approach

Sum of rows/cols of a matrix A can be seen as a matrix-vector multiplication where the elements of the vector are all ones. it can be represented by the following matlab code.

```
y = A * ones(size(A,2),1);
```

where `y` is the sum of rows of A.

cuBLAS libary provides a high performance matrix-vector multiplication function [`cublas<t>gemv()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_7_2) for this operation.

Timing result shows that this routine is only 10~50% slower than simply read all the elements of A once, which can be seen as the theoretical upper limit of the performance for this operation.

Comment: Pursuant to the matrix-vector multiply, Sorensen has a nice paper on wringing the most performance out of that operation depending on the shape of the matrix:  http://gpulab.imm.dtu.dk/papers/Sorensen2012_Euro-Par.pdf

Comment: @Eric I saw this idea in previous StackOverflow questions. I mentioned row sums because it is standard, but what I would really be able to do   is row AND/OR operations (instead of sums). For rowAND or rowOR I can't use your trick. Anyways, thanks a lot for trying to answer my question.

Comment: @Novak very nice paper. It use different kernels to deal with different situations. Cublas routines may only consider generally good situations...neither too high nor too wide

Comment: @ChuckKillerDoll general multi-reduction can be done by thrust::reduction_by_key  you can find some discussions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698969/cuda-thrust-find-index-of-minimum-value-among-multiple-vectors/17718468#17718468   for highest performance, u still need write your own kernel. Standard reduction kernel is a good template for multi-reduction since multi-reduction  is in fact the first step of standard reduction. I may add something about this later.

Answer (score 9):

**Reducing the rows of a matrix** can be solved by using **CUDA Thrust** in three ways (they may not be the only ones, but addressing this point is out of scope). As also recognized by the same OP, using CUDA Thrust is preferable for such a kind of problem. Also, an approach using **cuBLAS** is possible.

**APPROACH #1 - `reduce_by_key`**

This is the approach suggested at this [Thrust example page](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/sum_rows.cu). It includes a variant using `make_discard_iterator`.

**APPROACH #2 - `transform`**

This is the approach suggested by Robert Crovella at [CUDA Thrust: reduce_by_key on only some values in an array, based off values in a “key” array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989178/cuda-thrust-reduce-by-key-on-only-some-values-in-an-array-based-off-values-in).

**APPROACH #3 - `inclusive_scan_by_key`**

This is the approach suggested by Eric at [How to normalize matrix columns in CUDA with max performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211093/how-to-normalize-matrix-columns-in-cuda-with-max-performance).

**APPROACH #4 - `cublas<t>gemv`**

It uses `cuBLAS` `gemv` to multiply the relevant matrix by a column of `1`'s.

**THE FULL CODE**

Here is the code condensing the two approaches. The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are mantained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) and omitted here. The `TimingGPU.cu` and `TimingGPU.cuh` are maintained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/Timing) and are omitted as well.

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

// --- Required for approach #2
__device__ float *vals;

/**************************************************************/
/* CONVERT LINEAR INDEX TO ROW INDEX - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #1 */
/**************************************************************/
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T> {

    T Ncols; // --- Number of columns

    __host__ __device__ linear_index_to_row_index(T Ncols) : Ncols(Ncols) {}

    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T i) { return i / Ncols; }
};

/******************************************/
/* ROW_REDUCTION - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #2 */
/******************************************/
struct row_reduction {

    const int Ncols;    // --- Number of columns

    row_reduction(int _Ncols) : Ncols(_Ncols) {}

    __device__ float operator()(float& x, int& y ) {
        float temp = 0.f;
        for (int i = 0; i<Ncols; i++)
            temp += vals[i + (y*Ncols)];
        return temp;
    }
};

/**************************/
/* NEEDED FOR APPROACH #3 */
/**************************/
template<typename T>
struct MulC: public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
    T C;
    __host__ __device__ MulC(T c) : C(c) { }
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T x) { return x * C; }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Nrows = 5;     // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 8;     // --- Number of columns

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix(Nrows * Ncols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix.size(); i++) d_matrix[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #1 */
    /***************/
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    // --- Allocate space for row sums and indices
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_row_sums(Nrows);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_row_indices(Nrows);

    // --- Compute row sums by summing values with equal row indices
    //thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)),
    //                    thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
    //                    d_matrix.begin(),
    //                    d_row_indices.begin(),
    //                    d_row_sums.begin(),
    //                    thrust::equal_to<int>(),
    //                    thrust::plus<float>());

    thrust::reduce_by_key(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
                d_matrix.begin(),
                thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
                d_row_sums.begin());

    printf("Timing for approach #1 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Print result
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_row_sums[i] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #2 */
    /***************/
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_row_sums_2(Nrows, 0);
    float *s_vals = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_matrix[0]);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(vals, &s_vals, sizeof(float *)));
    thrust::transform(d_row_sums_2.begin(), d_row_sums_2.end(), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),  d_row_sums_2.begin(), row_reduction(Ncols));

    printf("Timing for approach #2 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_row_sums_2[i] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #3 */
    /***************/

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_row_sums_3(Nrows, 0);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_temp(Nrows * Ncols);
    thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Ncols)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
                d_matrix.begin(),
                d_temp.begin());
    thrust::copy(
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_temp.begin() + Ncols - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(Ncols))),
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_temp.begin() + Ncols - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(Ncols))) + Nrows,
                d_row_sums_3.begin());

    printf("Timing for approach #3 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_row_sums_3[i] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #4 */
    /***************/
    cublasHandle_t handle;

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_row_sums_4(Nrows);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_ones(Ncols, 1.f);

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Ncols, Nrows, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix.data()), Ncols, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_row_sums_4.data()), 1));

    printf("Timing for approach #4 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_row_sums_4[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**TIMING RESULTS** (tested on a Kepler K20c)

```
Matrix size       #1     #1-v2     #2     #3     #4     #4 (no plan)
100  x 100        0.63   1.00     0.10    0.18   139.4  0.098
1000 x 1000       1.25   1.12     3.25    1.04   101.3  0.12
5000 x 5000       8.38   15.3     16.05   13.8   111.3  1.14

 100 x 5000       1.25   1.52     2.92    1.75   101.2  0.40    

5000 x 100        1.35   1.99     0.37    1.74   139.2  0.14
```

It seems that approaches #1 and #3 outperform approach #2, except in the cases of small numbers of columns. The best approach, however, is approach #4, which is significantly more convenient than the others, provided that the time needed to create the plan can be amortized during the computation.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'plan' in the #4? Does it mean the time needed to call 'cublasCreate'?

Answer (score 4):

If this is the extent (summing the rows) of the operations you need to do with this data, I wouldn't expect a sizable benefit from the GPU.  You have exactly one arithmetic operation per data element, and for that you are paying the cost of transferring that data element to the GPU.  And beyond a certain problem size (whatever it takes to keep the machine busy) you get no added benefit from larger problem sizes, because the arithmetic intensity is O(n).

So this isn't a particularly exciting problem to solve on the GPU.

But as talonmies has indicated, you have a coalescing problem in the way you have crafted it, which will further slow things down.  Let's take a look at a small example:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1  11  12  13  14
R2  21  22  23  24
R3  31  32  33  34
R4  41  42  43  44
```

Above is a simple pictorial example of a small portion of your matrix.  The machine data storage is such that elements (11), (12), (13), and (14) are stored in adjacent memory locations.

For *coalesced* access, we want an access pattern such that adjacent memory locations are requested from the same instruction, executed across the warp.

We need to think about execution of your code from the standpoint of a *warp*, that is 32 threads executing in lock-step.  What is your code doing?  Which elements is it retrieving (asking for) at each step/instruction?  Let's take a look at this line of code:

```
        sum+=m[rowIdx*ncol+k];
```

Adjacent threads in the warp have adjacent (i.e. consecutive) values for `rowIdx` as you have created that variable.  So when `k` = 0, which data element is being asked for by each thread when we try to retrieve the value `m[rowIdx*ncol+k]` ?

In block 0, thread 0 has a `rowIdx` of 0.  Thread 1 has a `rowIdx` of 1, etc.  So the values being asked for by each thread at this instruction are:

```
Thread:   Memory Location:    Matrix Element:
     0      m[0]                   (11)
     1      m[ncol]                (21)
     2      m[2*ncol]              (31)
     3      m[3*ncol]              (41)
```

But this is not coalesced access! Elements (11), (21), etc. are not adjacent in memory. For coalesced access, we would like that Matrix Element row to read like this:

```
Thread:   Memory Location:    Matrix Element:
     0      m[?]                   (11)
     1      m[?]                   (12)
     2      m[?]                   (13)
     3      m[?]                   (14)
```

If you then work backwards to determine what the value of `?` should be, you will come up with an instruction something like this:

```
        sum+=m[k*ncol+rowIdx];
```

This will give coalesced access, but it will not give you the correct answer, because we are now summing matrix *columns* instead of matrix *rows*.  We can fix this by re-organizing your data storage to be in column-major order rather than row-major order.  (You should be able to google that for ideas, right?)  Conceptually, this is equivalent to transposing your matrix `m`.  Whether this is convenient for you to do or not is outside the scope of your question, as I see it, and not really a CUDA issue.    It may be a simple thing for you to do as you are creating the matrix on the host or transferring the matrix from host to device.  But in summary, I don't know of a way to sum the matrix rows with 100% coalesced access, if the matrix is stored in row-major order.   (You could resort to a sequence of row-reductions but that looks painful to me.)

It's not uncommon, when we are thinking about ways to accelerate code on the GPU, to consider re-organizing our data storage to facilitate the GPU.  This is one example.

And, yes, what I'm outlining here still retains a loop in the kernel.

As an additional comment, I would suggest timing the data copy portions, and kernel (compute) portions separately.  I can't tell from your question whether you are timing just the kernel or the entire (GPU) operation, including the data copies.  If you time the data copies separately, you may discover that just the data copy time exceeds your CPU time.   Any effort put into optimizing your CUDA code will not affect the data copy time.  This might be a useful data point before you spend much time on this.

Comment: first of all, thanks for clarifying what a "coalesced memory access" means. When you say: "..I don't know of a way to sum the matrix rows with 100% coalesced access, if the matrix is stored in row-major order..." I come with this idea: sum+=m[blockIdx.x*ncol + threadIdx.x], where you launch the kernel with threadIdx.x == ncol. In this case, isn't the memory access coalesced?

Comment: `threadIdx.x == ncol` makes no sense.  You don't get to pick `threadIdx.x`.  I assume you mean the number of threads per block == ncol.  Your redefined `sum` is indeed generating coalesced access, but you are still summing columns, at least with reference to the original storage format assumption of row-major order.  And since your sum no longer depends on the loop variable `k`, it's really a bit silly to suggest that change in the context of your question.  Asking new questions in the comments is difficult to deal with.  I really think @Eric gave you a good answer.  I have upvoted it.

Comment: @Eric obviously I meant calling the kernel with block == ncol. I am not asking a new question, I was just asking what do you think about the idea of using `sum+=m[blockIdx.x*ncol + threadIdx.x]`, if you arrange this way you are coalescing, because you are sweeping adjacent memory elemnts, given the the vector is deployed by row.

Comment: I am not Eric.  It was not obvious to me that you mean block==ncol. And I already stated you'll get coalesced access but not the answer you desire, as you are essentially summing columns not rows.  And as I stated already, this one line of code would need a modified kernel around it to make any sense.  it would not make sense to drop this line into the existing kernel code you have proposed.  In effect you have each block working on a single row.  It's not clear to me how you would realize the summation (or whatever operation you choose) without a reduction technique, i.e. a different kernel.

Comment: Sorry about the Eric mention @RobertCrovella. Why I said that it takes adjacent address of memory is because if you use `sum+=m[blockIdx.x*ncol + threadIdx.x]` and look at block 0, thread 0 you have m[0], if you pick block 0, thread 1, you have m[1] and so on. When you move to the next block, you have: block 1, thread 1 m[ncol], block 1, thread 1 m[ncol+1]. Why isn't it not coalesced? memory?

Comment: Where did I say it is not coalesced?

Comment: "...it's really a bit silly to suggest that change in the context of your question.."

Comment: Anyways, sorry any misunderstanding...the loop will stay and I will post a code with my final thoughts. Again, thanks for clarifying the "memory coalescing"

Comment: I said it was coalesced not once but twice.  The comment you have excerpted, I preceded with "since your sum no longer depends on the loop variable k, ".  It's silly because it makes no use of the loop variable k.  Why don't you drop that code into your loop that you have posed in this question and see if it makes sense.  It does not.

Comment: there is no code yet, only a comment on how to deal with the sum variable, just that. Anywyays, I am coding here and will post a complete answer, based on your comments. I hope it makes things faster...