# How sum grouped in Cuda

Tags: cuda

I would like to know what techniques I could apply to add some dimensions of an array and save to a new Vet lower as in the following example:

A -> [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]

B ->  [3],   [7],   [11]

figure:
http://snag.gy/83Qwl.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA code for sum of rows of a matrix too slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/cuda-code-for-sum-of-rows-of-a-matrix-too-slow)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own CUDA kernel, take a look at the [Vector add sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition).  Instead of passing 2 input vectors to the kernel, you would pass just `A` and provide a loop to sum over the "rows" of `A`:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *A, int *B, int rows, int cols){
  int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < rows) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i< cols; i++)
      sum += A[(idx*cols)+i];
    B[idx] = sum;
    }
}
```

This won't be terribly efficient, but you can improve the efficiency if you can store your `A` array in column major order:

```
A -> [1,3,5], [2,4,6]
```

then a modification to the above kernel becomes pretty efficient:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *A, int *B, int rows, int cols){
  int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < rows) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i< cols; i++)
      sum += A[(i*cols)+idx];
    B[idx] = sum;
    }
}
```

If you're looking for efficiency but can't reorganize your data, then a segmented parallel reduction will be fastest.  You can try creating something based on the [cuda sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) but I would suggest using [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), specifically [reduce_by_key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad)

You would leave your `A` array as is and use it as the "values":

```
A -> [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
```

And you would create a "key" array which corresponds to the rows of your A array:

```
K -> [0,0], [1,1], [2,2]
```