# Computing all-pairs distances between points in different sets with CUDA

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to implement a brute force distance computation algorithm in CUDA.

```
#define VECTOR_DIM 128
thrust::device_vector<float> feature_data_1;
feature_data_1.resize(VECTOR_DIM * 1000); // 1000 128 dimensional points
thrust::device_vector<float> feature_data_2;
feature_data_2.resize(VECTOR_DIM * 2000); // 2000 128 dimensional points
```

Now what I would like to do is to compute the `L2` distances (sum of the squared differences) from every vector in the first matrix to every vector in the second matrix.

So, if array `1` is of size `1000` and array `2` is of size `2000`, the result would be a floating point matrix of `1000*2000` in size.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this using Thrust algorithms alone.

Comment: It should be possible.  However you've crafted a data storage arrangement that is an Array of Structures (AoS).  This is not particularly conducive to good GPU performance (whether CUDA or Thrust).  If you want to accomplish this efficiently, you should almost certainly rearrange your data to something that approximates SoA.

Comment: I realized that while looking at some of your other posts. I am doing that refactoring now. I will update the thread.

Comment: I think that you can notice the following: `||x-y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2-2*<x,y>`, where `<x,y>` denotes the scalar product between `x` and `y`. If you assume row major ordering of the `x` and `y` vectors into `X` and `Y` matrices, then you can use something like [Reduce matrix rows with CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/reduce-matrix-rows-with-cuda) to calculate all the needed `||x||^2` and `||y||^2`. The scalar products `<x,y>` can then be calculated as the matrix-matrix multiplication `X*Y^T` using `cublas<t>gemm()`.

Comment: @JackOLantern: My issue with this is that the number of points in x and y could be different (same dimensions but variable observations) but perhaps I can take that into account easily.

Comment: In my understanding (but of course my understanding can be wrong) of your problem, this should be irrelevant. Resuming your example, `X` should be a `1000 x 128` matrix, while `Y` should be a `2000 x 128` matrix. But everything should match the approach outlined above. You have to think to organize your `128`-dimensional vectors of the first and second groups into matrices. The important thing is that both the matrices contain `128`-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Missed the transpose there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the all-pairs distances between points in two different sets in CUDA can be solved by observing that

```
||x-y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2-2*<x,y>
```

where `|| ||` is the `l2` norm and `<x,y>` denotes the scalar product between `x` and `y`.

The norms `||x||` and `||y||` can be calculated by approaches inspired by [Reduce matrix rows with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/reduce-matrix-rows-with-cuda), while the scalar products `<x,y>` can then be calculated as the matrix-matrix multiplication `X*Y^T` using `cublas<t>gemm()`.

Below is a fully worked out implementation. Please, note that for the calculation of the norms `|| ||` two approaches are reported, one using `cuBLAS` `cublas<t>gemv` and one using Thurst's `transform`. For the problem size of your interest, I have experienced the following timings on my GT540M card:

```
Approach nr. 1    0.12ms
Approach nr. 2    0.59ms

include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCK_SIZE_X 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y 16

/***********************************************************/
/* SQUARED ABSOLUTE VALUE FUNCTOR - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #1 */
/***********************************************************/
struct abs2 {
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(const float &x) const { return x * x; }
};

// --- Required for approach #2
__device__ float *vals;

/******************************************/
/* ROW_REDUCTION - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #2 */
/******************************************/
struct row_reduction {

    const int Ncols;    // --- Number of columns

    row_reduction(int _Ncols) : Ncols(_Ncols) {}

    __device__ float operator()(float& x, int& y ) {
        float temp = 0.f;
        for (int i = 0; i<Ncols; i++)
            temp += vals[i + (y*Ncols)] * vals[i + (y*Ncols)];
        return temp;
    }
};

/************************************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION TO ASSEMBLE THE FINAL RESULT */
/************************************************/
__global__ void assemble_final_result(const float * __restrict__ d_norms_x_2, const float * __restrict__ d_norms_y_2, float * __restrict__ d_dots,
                                      const int NX, const int NY) {

    const int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * gridDim.x;
    const int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * gridDim.y;

    if ((i < NY) && (j < NX)) d_dots[i * NX+ j] = d_norms_x_2[j] + d_norms_y_2[i] - 2 * d_dots[i * NX+ j];

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    //const int Ndims = 128;        // --- Number of rows
    //const int NX  = 1000;     // --- Number of columns
    //const int NY  = 2000;     // --- Number of columns

    const int Ndims = 3;        // --- Number of rows
    const int NX    = 4;        // --- Number of columns
    const int NY    = 5;        // --- Number of columns

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrices allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_X(Ndims * NX);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_Y(Ndims * NY);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_X.size(); i++) d_X[i] = (float)dist(rng);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_Y.size(); i++) d_Y[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    // --- cuBLAS handle creation
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    /**********************************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE NORMS OF THE ELEMENTS OF X */
    /**********************************************/
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_norms_x_2(NX);

    // --- Approach nr. 1
    //timerGPU.StartCounter();
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_X_2(Ndims * NX);
    thrust::transform(d_X.begin(), d_X.end(), d_X_2.begin(), abs2());

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_ones(Ndims, 1.f);

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Ndims, NX, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X_2.data()), Ndims, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_norms_x_2.data()), 1));

    //printf("Timing for approach #1 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Approach nr. 2
    //timerGPU.StartCounter();
 //   float *s_vals = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_X[0]);
 //   gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(vals, &s_vals, sizeof(float *)));
 //   thrust::transform(d_norms_x_2.begin(), d_norms_x_2.end(), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),  d_norms_x_2.begin(), row_reduction(Ndims));

    //printf("Timing for approach #2 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    /**********************************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE NORMS OF THE ELEMENTS OF Y */
    /**********************************************/
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_norms_y_2(NX);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_Y_2(Ndims * NX);
    thrust::transform(d_Y.begin(), d_Y.end(), d_Y_2.begin(), abs2());

    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Ndims, NY, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Y_2.data()), Ndims, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_norms_y_2.data()), 1));


    /***********************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE SCALAR PRODUCTS */
    /***********************************/
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_dots(NX * NY);

    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, NX, NY, Ndims, &alpha,
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X.data()), Ndims, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Y.data()), Ndims, &beta,
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_dots.data()), NX));

    /*****************************/
    /* ASSEMBLE THE FINAL RESULT */
    /*****************************/

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_X, BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid(iDivUp(NX, BLOCK_SIZE_X), iDivUp(NY, BLOCK_SIZE_Y));
    assemble_final_result<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_norms_x_2.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_norms_y_2.data()), 
                                                 thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_dots.data()), NX, NY);

    for(int i = 0; i < NX * NY; i++) std::cout << d_dots[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are mantained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) and omitted here. The `TimingGPU.cu` and `TimingGPU.cuh` are maintained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/Timing) and are omitted as well.

Comment: Can you comment on what this line is doing?
cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Ndims, NX, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X_2.data()), Ndims, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_norms_x_2.data()), 1));