# Reduce matrix columns with CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a matrix and I would like to use CUDA and in the fastest possible way compute the column-wise mean (boils down to be simply the sum), i.e., return a row vector containing the mean of every column in that matrix. A sum reduction implementation for computing the sum of a single column vector looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void kernelSum(const T* __restrict__ input, T* __restrict__ per_block_results, const size_t n) {
    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // load input into __shared__ memory
    T x = 0.0;
    if (tid < n) {
        x = input[tid];
    }
    sdata[threadIdx.x] = x;
    __syncthreads();

    // contiguous range pattern
    for(int offset = blockDim.x / 2; offset > 0; offset >>= 1) {
        if(threadIdx.x < offset) {
            // add a partial sum upstream to our own
            sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
        }
        // wait until all threads in the block have
        // updated their partial sums
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // thread 0 writes the final result
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) {
        per_block_results[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
}
```

and this is invoked as:

```
int n = ... // vector size
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1024;
int number_of_blocks = (n + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
double* per_block_results = NULL;
cudaMalloc((void**) &per_block_results, sizeof(double)*(number_of_blocks + 1));
// launch one kernel to compute, per-block, a partial sum
kernelSum<double> <<<number_of_blocks, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(double)>>>(a, per_block_results, n);
// launch a single block to compute the sum of the partial sums
kernelSum<double> <<<1, number_of_blocks, number_of_blocks*sizeof(double)>>>(per_block_results, per_block_results + number_of_blocks, number_of_blocks);
```

I could generalize this kernel to matrices of any number of columns but I'm limited by the shared memory. My GPU has compute capability `3.5` so it has `48KB` of shared memory and a maximum block size of `1024` i.e. number of threads per block. Since I am interested in double-precision, I have `48*1024/8= 6144` maximum doubles of shared memory. Since the reduction is done per block, I can have a maximum of `6144 (doubles in shared memory) / 1024 (block size) = 6` columns for which I can compute the sum reduction simultaneously. Reducing the block size then would allow to compute more columns simultaneously e.g. `6144 (doubles in shared memory) / 512 (block size) = 12`.

Would this more complex strategy beat the simple CPU loop over every column of the matrix and invoke the sum reduction. Is there yet another better way to do this?

Comment: A simple alternative would be to set up your problem as a matrix vector product between your matrix and a vector of all `1`'s using `cublas<t>gemv()`.

Comment: Indeed, a solution is actually given matrix A to do: A^T*1, this gives back the sum column-wise. Please elaborate an answer and I will accept. But on the downside doing so much FLOP for nothing feels like a waste. It reads: I would be misusing the GEMV kernel because there is actually no multiplications needed.

Comment: @talonmies has given an answer to your specific question. It is true that you are somewhat misusing `cublas<t>gemv()` in that you are loading the dummy `1`'s vector and multiplying the elements of the matrix `A` by them. But the cuBLAS routines are highly optimized and it would be interesting to assess whether your own implementation is faster or not than the "naive" cuBLAS one we are talking about. Perhaps, you can be interested to make a comparison to talonmie's solution and post your results here...

Comment: Is your matrix data stored in row-major (e.g. C-style) or column-major (e.g. Fortran-style) order?  A matrix-column sums kernel for row-major storage is trivial and requires no shared memory usage.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Indeed, although unless the matrix has a lot of columns, it may be difficult to approach peak memory bandwidth using one thread per column.

Comment: I think @JackOLantern is right, for my matrix (it's of size 26000x29) `cublas<t>gemv()` is pretty fast despite dummy operations -- it's even faster than the `kernelSum` kernel in the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is stopping you doing something like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void kernelSum(const T* __restrict__ input, 
                          T* __restrict__ per_block_results, 
                          const size_t lda, const size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    // Accumulate per thread partial sum
    T x = 0.0;
    T * p = &input[blockIdx.x * lda];
    for(int i=threadIdx.x; i < n; i += blockDim.x) {
        x += p[i];
    }

    // load partial sum into __shared__ memory
    sdata[threadIdx.x] = x;
    __syncthreads();

    // contiguous range pattern
    for(int offset = blockDim.x / 2; offset > 0; offset >>= 1) {
        if(threadIdx.x < offset) {
            // add a partial sum upstream to our own
            sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
        }
        // wait until all threads in the block have
        // updated their partial sums
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // thread 0 writes the final result
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) {
        per_block_results[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
}
```

[standard disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or tested, use at own risk]

ie. you only need one entry in `sdata`  for each thread in the block for the shared memory reduction. Each thread sums as many values as required to cover the full column input. Then there is no shared memory restriction, you can sum any size column with the same block size.

---

EDIT: Apparently the idea of using per thread partial sums is new to you, so here is a complete example to study:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
__global__ 
void kernelSum(const T* __restrict__ input, 
        const size_t lda, // pitch of input in words of sizeof(T)
        T* __restrict__ per_block_results, 
                const size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    T x = 0.0;
    const T * p = &input[blockIdx.x * lda];
    // Accumulate per thread partial sum
    for(int i=threadIdx.x; i < n; i += blockDim.x) {
        x += p[i];
    }

    // load thread partial sum into shared memory
    sdata[threadIdx.x] = x;
    __syncthreads();

    for(int offset = blockDim.x / 2; offset > 0; offset >>= 1) {
        if(threadIdx.x < offset) {
            sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // thread 0 writes the final result
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) {
        per_block_results[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    const int m = 10000, n = 16;
    float * a = new float[m*n];

    for(int i=0; i<(m*n); i++) { a[i] = (float)(i%10); }

    float *a_;
    size_t size_a = m * n * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&a_, size_a);
    cudaMemcpy(a_, a, size_a, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    float *b_;
    size_t size_b = n * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&b_, size_b);

    // select number of warps per block according to size of the
    // colum and launch one block per column. Probably makes sense
    // to have at least 4:1 column size to block size
    dim3 blocksize(256); 
    dim3 gridsize(n);
    size_t shmsize = sizeof(float) * (size_t)blocksize.x;
    kernelSum<float><<<gridsize, blocksize, shmsize>>>(a_, b_, m, m);

    float * b = new float[n];
    cudaMemcpy(b, b_, size_b, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       std::cout << i << " " << b[i] << std::endl;
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

You should experiment with the block size relative to your matrix size for optimal performance, but in general the more work per thread the kernel does, the better the overall performance will be (because the shared memory reduction is quite expensive). You can see one approach to block and grid size heuristics for similarly memory bandwidth bound problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810780/681865).

Comment: I'm sorry can you please provide a sample kernel invocation, I can't still see how this works.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: Please look at the code in the edit. Based on your comments on this an another answer of mine for a memset kernel, it seems you might want to spend some time working through the whole "mutiple data items per thread" design pattern. It is an extremely powerful technique for improving performance in simple, memory bound operations like this one.

Comment: Great and self-contained answer, but looks like the function call to `kernelSum` is wrong, it should be `kernelSum<float><<<gridsize, blocksize, shmsize>>>(a_, m, b_, m);`

Answer (score 3):

As alternatives to the answer already provided by talonmies, I'm here reporting `4` other approaches for column reduction, `3` of them based on using CUDA Thrust and `1` based on using `cublas<t>gemv()` with a column of `1`'s, as suggested in my comment above.

The CUDA Thrust approaches are the analogous of [Reduce matrix rows with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/reduce-matrix-rows-with-cuda/29525897#29525897) with an implicit transposition obtained by

```
thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_matrix.begin(),                 
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                (_1 % Nrows) * Ncols + _1 / Nrows))
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

// --- Required for approach #2
__device__ float *vals;

/**************************************************************/
/* CONVERT LINEAR INDEX TO ROW INDEX - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #1 */
/**************************************************************/
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T> {

    T Ncols; // --- Number of columns

    __host__ __device__ linear_index_to_row_index(T Ncols) : Ncols(Ncols) {}

    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T i) { return i / Ncols; }
};

/******************************************/
/* ROW_REDUCTION - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #2 */
/******************************************/
struct col_reduction {

    const int Nrows;    // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols;    // --- Number of cols

    col_reduction(int _Nrows, int _Ncols) : Nrows(_Nrows), Ncols(_Ncols) {}

    __device__ float operator()(float& x, int& y ) {
        float temp = 0.f;
        for (int i = 0; i<Nrows; i++) {
            temp += vals[y + (i*Ncols)];
        }
        return temp;
    }
};

/**************************/
/* NEEDED FOR APPROACH #3 */
/**************************/
template<typename T>
struct MulC: public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
    T C;
    __host__ __device__ MulC(T c) : C(c) { }
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T x) { return x * C; }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Nrows = 5;     // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 8;     // --- Number of columns

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix(Nrows * Ncols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix.size(); i++) d_matrix[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #1 */
    /***************/
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    // --- Allocate space for row sums and indices
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_col_sums(Ncols);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_col_indices(Ncols);

    // --- Compute row sums by summing values with equal row indices
    thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)),
                          thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
                          thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                                d_matrix.begin(),
                                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),(_1 % Nrows) * Ncols + _1 / Nrows)),
                          d_col_indices.begin(),
                          d_col_sums.begin(),
                          thrust::equal_to<int>(),
                          thrust::plus<float>());

    //thrust::reduce_by_key(
 //               thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)),
 //               thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
 //               thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
    //              d_matrix.begin(),
    //              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),(_1 % Nrows) * Ncols + _1 / Nrows)),
 //               thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
 //               d_col_sums.begin());

    printf("Timing for approach #1 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Print result
    for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_col_sums[j] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #2 */
    /***************/
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_col_sums_2(Ncols, 0);
    float *s_vals = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_matrix[0]);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(vals, &s_vals, sizeof(float *)));
    thrust::transform(d_col_sums_2.begin(), d_col_sums_2.end(), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), d_col_sums_2.begin(), col_reduction(Nrows, Ncols));

    printf("Timing for approach #2 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_col_sums_2[j] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #3 */
    /***************/

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_col_sums_3(Ncols, 0);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_temp(Nrows * Ncols);
    thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nrows)) + (Nrows*Ncols),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_matrix.begin(),
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),(_1 % Nrows) * Ncols + _1 / Nrows)),
                d_temp.begin());
    thrust::copy(
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_temp.begin() + Nrows - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(Nrows))),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_temp.begin() + Nrows - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(Nrows))) + Ncols,
                d_col_sums_3.begin());

    printf("Timing for approach #3 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_col_sums_3[j] << "\n";
    }

    /***************/
    /* APPROACH #4 */
    /***************/
    cublasHandle_t handle;

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_col_sums_4(Ncols);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_ones(Nrows, 1.f);

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, Ncols, Nrows, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix.data()), Ncols, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_col_sums_4.data()), 1));

    printf("Timing for approach #4 = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << d_col_sums_4[j] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```